# Meteor.js using value of a helper as template

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, spacebars

I would like to render different template based on a helper value. I will try to write and example.

```
...
{{#with myHelper}}
 {{> this }}
{{/with}}
...
```

with the helper define like this for example:

```
...
myHelper : function(){
  return MyCollection.findOne({ userId: Meteor.userId() }).personalizeTemplate; 
}
...
```

Unfortunately in this way doesn't work. There could be any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [dynamic template](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) You don't even need the `{{#with}}`

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=myHelper }}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much... It was just what I need

Answer (score 0):

To use templates dynamically you have to use the global [`Template.dynamic`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic) :

```
{{> Template.dynamic template="my template"}}

{{> Template.dynamic template=myHelper}}
```

Note that `myHelper` must return a String which is the name of the template.
You may also provide a data context with `data` :

```
{{> Template.dynamic template=myTemplate data=someData}}
```

[Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/blaze-dynamic-template-includes/) wrote an article about it. It was created back in 2014 and the `UI` namespace used throughout the article has since been renamed `Template`.